# React Form validation displaying error

Tags: forms, reactjs, validation

I am using [React-Validation-Mixin](https://github.com/jurassix/react-validation-mixin) together with [Joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi) and Joi-Validation-Strategy to do some validations on a React Step/Wizard Form.

I have a parent `FormStart` Element that receives the state of its `FormStep` children through props.

The validation correctly signals that the input is required, but when I write a correct number in the browser (5 numbers as in PLZ/ZIP-Code), it will still signal that the input is invalid, even though the `zip` state shows a correct 5-digit number, so the next button never takes me to the next Form step.

```js
class FormStart extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
     step: 1,
     zip: ""
   }
    this.goToNext = this.goToNext.bind(this);
  }

  goToNext() {
    const { step } = this.state;
    if (step !== 10) {
      this.setState({ step: step + 1 });
      if (step == 9) {
    
        const values = {
          zip: this.state.zip,
        };

        console.log(values);
        // submit `values` to the server here.
      }
    }
  }

  handleChange(field) {
    return (evt) => this.setState({ [field]: evt.target.value });
  }

  render(){
    switch (this.state.step) {
    case 1:
      return <FormButton
        onSubmit={this.goToNext}
      />;
    //omitting the other 8 cases 
    case 9:
      return <FormStep7
        onSubmit={this.goToNext}
        zip={this.state.zip}
        onZipChange={this.handleChange('zip')}
      />;
    case 10:
      return <FormSuccess/>;
    }
  }
}

export default FormStart;
```

The React console shows that the `zip` state is correctly changed, and the Validation object also receives the same correct 5-digit zip and still holds the correct value `onBlur`.

```js
class FormStep7 extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.validatorTypes = {
      PLZ: Joi.number().min(5).max(5).required().label('PLZ').options({
       language: {
        number: {
         base: 'wird benötigt',
          min: 'muss {{limit}} Nummern enthalten',
          max: 'muss {{limit}} Nummern enthalten'
       }
     }
      })
    };
    this.getValidatorData = this.getValidatorData.bind(this);
    this.getClasses = this.getClasses.bind(this);
    this.renderHelpText = this.renderHelpText.bind(this);  
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  getValidatorData() {
    return {
      PLZ: this.props.zip
    };
  }

  getClasses(field) {
    return classnames({
      'form-control': true,
      'has-error': !this.props.isValid(field)
    });
  }

  renderHelpText(message) {
    return (
     <span className='help-block'>{message}</span>
    );
  }

  handleSubmit(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    const onValidate = (error) => {
      if (error) {
        //form has errors; do not submit
      } else {
        this.props.onSubmit();
      }
    };
    this.props.validate(onValidate);
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
       <form role="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <div className='row'>
       <div className="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <div className='form-group'>
         <label htmlFor="zip">
         Einsatzort
         </label>
         <br />
         <input className={this.getClasses('PLZ')} id="PLZ" placeholder="Meine PLZ" type="text" onChange={this.props.onZipChange} onBlur={this.props.handleValidation('PLZ')} value={this.props.zip} />
         {this.renderHelpText(this.props.getValidationMessages('PLZ'))}
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>    

       <div className='row'>
         <div className="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
           <button className="btn btn-green btn-block">Next</button>
         </div>
       </div>

     </div>
   </form>
    );
  }
}

FormStep7.propTypes = {
  errors: PropTypes.object,
  validate: PropTypes.func,
  isValid: PropTypes.func,
  handleValidation: PropTypes.func,
  getValidationMessages: PropTypes.func,
  clearValidations: PropTypes.func
};

export default validation(strategy)(FormStep7);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the issue was on `Joi.number()`. I changed the validation to match a Regex String pattern and then it worked.

```
this.validatorTypes = {
  PLZ: Joi.string().regex(/^[0-9]{5}$/).label('PLZ').options({
    language: {
        string: {
            regex: {
                base: "mit 5 Nummern wird benötigt"
            }
        }
     }
  })
};
```